# How can I have a progress bar load with the completion of a process?

Tags: c#, process, progress-bar

I am using the following to ping a host name:

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = pingData;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        string result = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(result);
        if(p.HasExited)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = result;
            outPut = result;
            MessageBox.Show( "Ping request has completed. \n Results have been copied to the clipboard.");                
        }
```

Is there anyway I can have a progress bar "load" during the ping command and complete the loading when the ping has completed?

Thank you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping

Comment: The real question is, how are you going to determine what to put the progress bar at? You can definitely let a progress bar run while the process is executing, and update it, but unless you are going to read and interpret STD OUT (and even that won't work for "silent" processes), you wouldn't know what the value is. I could give you some generic threading code to update a progress bar, but as far as evaluate "process completion" I think you will be out of luck.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingcompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx even has an example of how to use Ping. Depending on how you want to display the progress bar, you could modify the example to have the event handler set a flag indicating that the ping has completed. Then add a while loop in the main execution thread that fills in the progress bar as a percent of the elapsed time / timeout value. Below is the example reformatted as an example

```
namespace PingTest
{
    using global::System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using global::System.Net.NetworkInformation;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary>
    /// The ping example.
    /// </summary>
    public class PingExample
    {
        #region Static Fields

        private static bool pingComplete;

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods and Operators

        public static void DisplayReply(PingReply reply)
        {
            if (reply == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("ping status: {0}", reply.Status);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Address: {0}", reply.Address);
                Console.WriteLine("RoundTrip time: {0}", reply.RoundtripTime);
                Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", reply.Options.Ttl);
                Console.WriteLine("Don't fragment: {0}", reply.Options.DontFragment);
                Console.WriteLine("Buffer size: {0}", reply.Buffer.Length);
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Ping needs a host or IP Address.");
            }

            string who = args[0];
            var waiter = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            var pingSender = new Ping();

            // When the PingCompleted event is raised, 
            // the PingCompletedCallback method is called.
            pingSender.PingCompleted += PingCompletedCallback;

            // Create a buffer of 32 bytes of data to be transmitted. 
            const string Data = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);

            // Wait 12 seconds for a reply. 
            const int Timeout = 12000;

            // Set options for transmission: 
            // The data can go through 64 gateways or routers 
            // before it is destroyed, and the data packet 
            // cannot be fragmented.
            var options = new PingOptions(64, true);

            Console.WriteLine("Time to live: {0}", options.Ttl);
            Console.WriteLine("Don't fragment: {0}", options.DontFragment);

            // Send the ping asynchronously. 
            // Use the waiter as the user token. 
            // When the callback completes, it can wake up this thread.
            pingComplete = false;
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            watch.Start();
            pingSender.SendAsync(who, Timeout, buffer, options, waiter);

            while (!pingComplete && watch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= Timeout)
            {
                // Do display stuff for your progress bar here.
            }

            // Prevent this example application from ending. 
            // A real application should do something useful 
            // when possible.
            waiter.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Ping example completed.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        private static void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the operation was canceled, display a message to the user. 
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping canceled.");

                // Let the main thread resume.  
                // UserToken is the AutoResetEvent object that the main thread  
                // is waiting for.
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }

            // If an error occurred, display the exception to the user. 
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ping failed:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.ToString());

                // Let the main thread resume. 
                ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
            }

            PingReply reply = e.Reply;
            pingComplete = true;

            DisplayReply(reply);

            // Let the main thread resume.
            ((AutoResetEvent)e.UserState).Set();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```